# terminal: displaying special characters

Tags: terminal, character-encoding

In some programs, such as `htop` the lines and frames are not displayed correctly. Instead, they are displayed as `-` and `/`.

[image]

But on another machine, they are displayed correctly as proper lines:

[image]

I am not sure if this is a terminal issue, or if perhaps some package is necessary.

In case it is relevant: My system is Debian Wheezy, my interpreter is `bash` and my terminal emulator is `gnome-terminal`

Comment: Have you tried changing the font used by the terminal?

Comment: That would be a possible solution if placeholder characters like a boxes or question marks were in place of the Unicode characters, but his example shows `htop` displaying ASCII characters. However, if the default terminal font is non-Unicode, then the encoding is likely also, so I've added that to my answer.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your top example is running with a non-Unicode locale (i.e. ASCII). Check your $LANG environment variable (try `export | grep LANG`); you will most likely not find a `.UTF-8` suffix. Try adding it:

```
export LANG=$LANG.UTF-8
```

Your other example is running with a UTF-8 locale, which should be the default for recent shells. It seems `htop` detects your locale and displays either ASCII or Unicode characters - so in the bottom picture, you get nice Unicode characters, while with ASCII you get some pretty makeshift ones. I'd suggest changing the locale of the top picture's machine to a Unicode one (see [Locale - Debian Wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/Locale#Standard)).

If that doesn't work, it might be that your **terminal emulator** is the problem. The default encoding could be non-Unicode. Change the default encoding of your terminal emulator to UTF-8 (in `xfce4-terminal` I found it in the Advanced tab). If you can't, it might be that your current font doesn't support Unicode: try changing your font to a Unicode one.

[Strangely, I found once I'd changed my locale to ASCII once in a shell session, `htop` always displays the ASCII characters, even after changing it back. That might be your issue, if for some reason you are changing your locale in your shell occasionally.]

Answer (score 5):

The odd thing is that `htop` uses ncurses, which can draw lines with/without Unicode.  However, looking at the source-code in [`CRT.c`](https://github.com/hishamhm/htop/blob/master/CRT.c#L610) shows the explanation:

```
#ifdef HAVE_LIBNCURSESW
   if(strcmp(nl_langinfo(CODESET), "UTF-8") == 0)
      CRT_utf8 = true;
   else
      CRT_utf8 = false;
#endif

   CRT_treeStr =
#ifdef HAVE_LIBNCURSESW
      CRT_utf8 ? CRT_treeStrUtf8 :
#endif
      CRT_treeStrAscii;
```

and the [`CRT_treeStrUtf8`](https://github.com/hishamhm/htop/blob/master/CRT.c#L144) value is

```
const char *CRT_treeStrUtf8[TREE_STR_COUNT] = {
   "\xe2\x94\x80", // TREE_STR_HORZ ─
   "\xe2\x94\x82", // TREE_STR_VERT │
   "\xe2\x94\x9c", // TREE_STR_RTEE ├
   "\xe2\x94\x94", // TREE_STR_BEND └
   "\xe2\x94\x8c", // TREE_STR_TEND ┌
   "+",            // TREE_STR_OPEN +
   "\xe2\x94\x80", // TREE_STR_SHUT ─
};
```

However, ncurses (any curses implementation) has portable symbols for these which do not rely upon whether the encoding is UTF-8 or not.  Some applications (such as [dialog](http://invisible-island.net/dialog/manpage/dialog.html)'s `--ascii-lines` option) provide an *option* for using ASCII line-drawing, but an application that does not even attempt to use the line-drawing provided in ncurses is not making effective use of the library.

In short, when you come across a program that behaves like that, you should report it as a bug to the developers.

Further reading:

- [*Line Graphics*](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_addch.3x.html#h3-Line-Graphics) (ncurses addch manual page)
- [**`border`**, **`wborder`**, **`box`**, **`hline`**, **`whline`**, **`vline`**, **`wvline`**,
  **`mvhline`**, **`mvwhline`**, **`mvvline`**, **`mvwvline`** - *create curses
  borders, horizontal and vertical lines*](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_border.3x.html)
- [**`dialog`** screenshots](http://invisible-island.net/dialog/dialog-figures.html) (***none*** require UTF-8 encoding to use line-drawing)

Comment: While it did not directly solve my problem (setting `LANG` / `LC_ALL` enables the expected Unicode line drawing chars in `htop`), this is very interesting. Thanks for taking the time to explain it!