# htop displays incorrectly on different vps

Tags: command-line, terminal

When I use "htop" command for linux (+F5), layout on 2 my vps different:

[image: First server]
[image: Second server]

Why on my first server I see broken tree?

Answer (score 1):

This is related to another which I answered recently, but the accepted answer in that case is unsuitable:

[terminal: displaying special characters](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/97688/terminal-displaying-special-characters)

The first screenshot clearly shows `htop` being run on a terminal where UTF-8 encoding is not supported, because the misdrawn text should be line-drawing characters.  The latter shows it using ASCII characters to imitate line-drawing characters.

The setting of `TERM` is irrelevant, because `htop` does not use the terminal description to decide *how* to draw lines.  It uses your locale environment variables to *choose* between two hardcoded schemes for drawing lines.  It uses the `nl_langinfo` call in [this ifdef](https://github.com/hishamhm/htop/blob/master/CRT.c#L611):

```
#ifdef HAVE_LIBNCURSESW
   if(strcmp(nl_langinfo(CODESET), "UTF-8") == 0)
      CRT_utf8 = true;
   else
      CRT_utf8 = false;
#endif
```

to decide (based on `LC_ALL`, `LC_CTYPE`, etc.), that your terminal supports UTF-8 and is configured to do this.

Further reading:

- [nl_langinfo, nl_langinfo_l - query language and locale information](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/nl_langinfo.3.html)
- [htop - interactive process viewer](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/htop.1.html)

Answer (score 0):

It's probably to do with your terminal on the vps server. You can check your terminal with

```
env|grep -i term
```

They are probably different.

edit 1

and do you have one of those in terminfo database ?

```
ls -l /lib/terminfo/x/
```

edit 2

Well different distributions can locate them at different locations.
documentation can be read,

`man 5 terminfo`

`less /etc/terminfo/README`

`man infocmp`

Comment: Same answer on both servers: TERM=xterm

Comment: On one my server(correct)  I see correct listing:
[total 36] But on my another (incorrect) server I see:  [No such file or directory] Correct file on this server in another directory: [ls -l /usr/share/terminfo/x]  Should I copy this file to [/lib/terminfo/x/] folder and reboot server?

Answer (score 0):

I'd interrogate the tool you're using to connect to these servers. This definitely looks like a terminal display issue, and since you're saying the environment variable `TERM=xterm` is being set identically on both, I'd make sure the options on your terminal emulator are also set consistently.